# Best serialization method for my data structure?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, serialization, boost

first question ever asked here. I've tried using Boost but just can't figure out how it would work with my structure here. Plus the .lib missing error keeps occurring even after adding it to additional libraries, etc. Like it worked for a couple runs then out of no where pops up again. The first time it was fixed by making a new project but I don't have time to keep doing that.

Anyways I've moved my code from Visual Studio to QT Creator. Now I'm reading some things about XML or JSon and thinking if I should attempt to implement it?

Thing is I have this whole day to figure out this serialization issue for my final project due tomorrow. Once I've got this, I need to make a GUI which I hope will be much easier. Thanks in advance. Below is my best attempt at using Boost

```
Hotel.h

class guestBook {
    protected:
    friend class roomBook;
    friend class hashMap;
    struct guest {
        int guestKey;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        guest *next;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize( Archive & ar )
        {
            ar( guestKey, firstName, lastName);
        }
    };
    guest* guestHashTable[tableSize];
    public:
    void writeGuestTable();
    void readGuestTable();
    void addGuest(string firstName, string lastName);
    int numberOfItemsInBucket(int index);
    void retrieveGuestID();
};
guestBook.cpp
void hashMap::writeGuestTable() {
    for(int x=0;x<tableSize;x++){
       guestHashTable[x] = new guest;
       guestHashTable[x]->guestKey = 0;
       guestHashTable[x]->firstName = "empty";
       guestHashTable[x]->lastName = "empty";
    }
    ofstream os("guestTable.txt", ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive archive( os );
    guest myData;
    archive( myData );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Why are you rolling your own hashmap structure? Try using containers from the Standard Library like [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead. This will save you a ton of debugging time and avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @tadman My instructor had assigned us to hard code our own hashmap structures so I followed some youtube videos. This gave me the idea to carry it on over to my final project but you might be right, maybe it'll make things much easier by using the std library. I'd just have to take a second to learn it. Would you recommend std::map for my struct up above?

Comment: If you're making a lookup table, `std::map` is what you want. There's a variety of other containers with different properties depending on what you need. If you're rolling you own implementation for academic reasons, look at how the Standard Library defines the interface. There's usually a separation of concerns between the map itself and the data it contains, that simplifies your design. Making a `std::map` work-alike is educational because you have a working reference implementation to compare to.

Comment: @RyanNguyen *My instructor had assigned us to hard code our own hashmap structures* -- Then you should write a generic one, and not hardwire it into your `guestBook` structure.

Comment: @tadman Appreciate the help! Looking at a std map library, it seems as if I can only link one value to a key, whereas my struct contains a key with multiple values contained within. I'm just not getting something here. I'll stop  asking questions though and mess around for an hour or two now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're saying to go with a more common hashmap structure? Is mine really different? When I first followed it on youtube I assumed it was a generic hashmap structure.

Comment: If you need multiple entries per slot then you need a two-layer structure: `std::map<std::string, std::list<Guest>>` for example. Keep in mind `std::map` deals with hash collisions for you, internally it could be a red-black tree or whatever, it just allows fast lookup based on a unique key of some type.

Comment: "The first time it was fixed by making a new project but I don't have time to keep doing that." All you had to do was to delete the build directory.

Comment: @RyanNguyen So if you want that hashmap for another assignment, are you going to copy and paste and change the types that the map is storing?  If so, then it isn't generic.  The assignment you were given was to implement a guess book -- the hashmap is just an implementation detail that should be factored out.  You also have a linked list hard-wired into the guessbook, which also lacks generic properties.  There should be no "next" pointer at all.  It should be just `mylinklist<guest>` or something to that end, and the maintenance of "next" pointers would be in mylinklist.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the [Cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) C++ serialization library. Its advantages over boost.serialization include: header only, newer/better template programming constructs, json archive, and portable binary archive. Its only disadvantages (in my opinion) are: it requires C++11 (for Visual Studio 2015 or newer), and it supports serialization of smart pointers only (i.e., cannot serialize raw pointers--but this simplifies the object tracking and keeps crud out of the archives, which is helpful for a nice, clean, json archive).

Here is the example from the [Quick Start Page](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html)

```
struct MyClass
{
  int x, y, z;

  // This method lets cereal know which data members to serialize
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & archive)
  {
    archive( x, y, z ); // serialize things by passing them to the archive
  }
};
```

Cereal also has [Standard Library Support](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/stl_support.html). If you have a `std::vector` of `guestBook` objects, then `#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>` is all that is needed (in addition to the `guestBook::serialize` method) to be able to write the vector to an archive.

Comment: Okay so I've tried implementing cereal to my program. Let's say I'm serializing the entire table of 100 structs, does my code look fine? Edited it in the OP

Comment: No. The function signature is not right. It needs to be a template method. The example ``MyClass`` is very close to what you are doing.

Comment: Still I'm really not understanding how to serialize 100 objects. I've place the template and serialize method inside of the struct. Do I just create the struct 100 times through a for loop. At this point I really don't know what I'm doing :(

Comment: I've updated the code in the OP and it's running free of any errors. Decided to write the archives as binary files because I'll only need to access it when I run the program. Basically I want to save the entire table upon closing the program and loading it when opening the program so that I can add/remove guests. Thing is I checked the text file and saw a few binary bits, so I'm sure not the whole table is being archived and written to file.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt (as you mentioned in tags), I would prefer to serialize class members with QDataStream, instead of adding new library (which actually adding new bugs!!), also making benefit from nice features of Qt like implicit sharing.

QDataStream produces binary serialized data and knows about the generic types and Qt classes such as QByteArray and QString ... and also guaranties the data type in all platforms to be same width and size so can be used as cross platform solutions.

```
class  TestClass{
    QString strA;
    QByteArray ba;
    int a;
    quint32 b;

    QByteArray serialize(){
        QByteArray serializedData;
        QDataStream ds(&serializedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        ds << strA;
        ds << ba;
        ds << a;
        ds << b;

        return serializedData;
    }

    static TestClass deserialize(QByteArray serializedData){
        TestClass deserializedClass;

        QDataStream ds(&serializedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        ds >> deserializedClass.strA;
        ds >> deserializedClass.ba;
        ds >> deserializedClass.a;
        ds >> deserializedClass.b;

        return deserializedClass;

    }
}
```